# Bind "this" to a function defined in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

In my React project, I created a utility function to render fields for my different redux-form's:

```
export const renderField = function(fieldConfig, fieldName) {
  //fieldHelper is provided by redux-form
  const fieldHelper = this.props.fields[fieldName];
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{fieldConfig.label}</label>
      <fieldConfig.fieldType
        {...fieldHelper}
        {...fieldConfig.props}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In one of the forms, I have a json config (FIELDS) to pass to this function:

```
const FIELDS = {
  name: {
    validate: validateName,
    fieldType: 'input',
    props: {
      className: 'name-field',
      type: 'text'
    }
  },
  description: {
    validate: validateDescription,
    fieldType: 'textarea',
    props: {
      className: 'desc-field',
      rows: 2,
      value: 'Add Description To Your Group',
      onBlur: this._hello // <--- ????????
    }
  }
}

class ShowGroup extends Component {
  _hello = () => {
    console.log(this); // this returns null or undefined
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="show-group">
        <form>
          {_.map(FIELDS, renderField.bind(this))}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  //a unique id for this form
  form:'ShowGroup',
  fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
  fields_def: FIELDS
})(
  connect(null, {})(ShowGroup)
);
```

I'd like to bind the `ShowGroup` component, to the `onBlur` callback function. How can I do it?

I moved `FIELDS` to the constructor, but still I don't get desired `this` in `_hello` function.

I know that `FIELDS` is defined outside of the class, and that's the main point of my question: I'd like to know how I can attach the context of the class, to that function. If it's absolutely not possible, how can I do it anyways?

Comment: It looks like that `FIELDS` is outside the class. `this` always refers to the current context you are in, whether it's a class, function or global. Where global `this` would be the same as `window`

Comment: as I mentioned, even when I move it inside the class (to the constructor) I get `null`/`undefined` for `this`.

Comment: Bind doesn't work with arrow functions.

Comment: Just wondering how you're planning on getting the arguments passed to `renderField`

Comment: That is handled by `redux-form` (look at the bottom of the code)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `bind()` and arrow function.

> Two factors influenced the introduction of arrow functions: shorter
>   functions and non-binding of this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Declare with `function` instead like `hello = function() {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a bind as well as an arrow function:

Change your `_hello` to:

```
_hello(){
    console.log(this); // this returns null or undefined
  };
```

Move your FIELDS inside the class, and, while assigning the to `onBlur`.
Do a bind,

`onBlur: this._hello.bind(this)`

Comment: THe problem is that then I lose pointer to FIELDS (look at the bottom of the code, I need to be able to point to FIELDS from outside of the class)

Comment: In that case, let it stay outside, but while calling `onBlur`. from inside your `renderFields` do a call `fieldConfig.props.onBlur.call(this)`

Comment: I pass the callback function as implicitly: `{...fieldConfig.props}`